# Limit na.locf in zoo package

Tags: r, na, zoo, locf

I would like to do a last observation carried forward for a variable, but only up to 2 observations. That is, for gaps of data of 3 or more NA, I would only carry the last observation forward for the next 2 observations and leave the rest as NA.

If I do this with the `zoo::na.locf`, the `maxgap` parameter implies that if the gap is larger than 2, no NA is replaced. Not even the last 2. Is there any alternative?

```
x <- c(NA,3,4,5,6,NA,NA,NA,7,8)
zoo::na.locf(x, maxgap = 2) # Doesn't replace the first 2 NAs of after the 6 as the gap of NA is 3. 
Desired_output <- c(NA,3,4,5,6,6,6,NA,7,8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using base R:

```
ave(x, cumsum(!is.na(x)), FUN = function(i){ i[1:pmin(length(i), 3)] <- i[1]; i })
# [1] NA  3  4  5  6  6  6 NA  7  8
```

`cumsum(!is.na(x))` groups each run of `NA`s with most recent non-`NA` value.

`function(i){ i[1:pmin(length(i), 3)] <- i[1]; i }` transforms the first two `NA`s of each group into the leading non-`NA` value of this group.

Comment: Nice.  A small simplification might be to use this as FUN: `function(x) ifelse(seq_along(x) <= 2+1, x[1], NA)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, good suggestion. My original function is quite clumsy.

Comment: I think it is very elegant to have a one liner although I am not very familiar with `ave` and `pmin`. How could you do the carry backwards? @mt1022 @G.Grothendieck

Comment: @user3507584, A possible way is: 1) reverse the vector; 2) transform reversed vector with the current answers; 3) reverse the transformed values.

Comment: @mt1022 Thanks for the guidance, I think I got it [using @G.Grothendieck suggestion for the function]: `rev(ave(rev(x), cumsum(!is.na(rev(x))), FUN = function(z) ifelse(seq_along(z) <= 3, z[1], NA)))`

Answer (score 5):

First apply `na.locf0` with `maxgap = 2` giving `x0` and define a grouping variable `g` using `rleid` from the data.table package.  For each such group use `ave` to apply `keeper` which if the group is all NA replaces it with c(1, 1, NA, ..., NA) and otherwise outputs all 1s.  Multiply `na.locf0(x)` by that.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

mg <- 2
x0 <- na.locf0(x, maxgap = mg)
g <- rleid(is.na(x0))
keeper <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x)))  ifelse(seq_along(x) <= mg, 1, NA) else 1
na.locf0(x) * ave(x0, g, FUN = keeper)
## [1] NA  3  4  5  6  6  6 NA  7  8
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to know what `rleid`, `ave` and `keeper` are doing in this case?

Comment: `rleid` creates a vector the same length as its input such that it assigns 1 to the first run, 2 to the second run and so on.  `keeper` is described in the answer.  `ave` splits the first argument into groups defined by the second argument, applies the specified function to each group and then puts it all back togeher.  Use `help` for further info.